# show many to many relationship field label in symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony, many-to-many, entity, label

I have an entity News bound to an entity Company with a many to many relationship.
Such relationship is set in a form through an entity field where I can select companies tied to my news.
Everything works fine except that company ids are showed as labels.

Is there a way to force another and more meaningful table field is showed as a label?

Answer (score 4):

Have look at `entity` form field type reference. Specifically `property` option.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#property

Comment: You are true thanks! I thought that property would refer to the table field used to get value attribute!

Comment: @Matteo: Please accept this answer if you are happy with it (click the little checkbox).  Welcome to Stack.